# Custom Keystroke for a custom string after number input in PDF

Tags: javascript, pdf, formatting, code-formatting, acrobat

I have a field labeled Area:[image]

I need to add SqFt to the end of the numbers within the field. I have spent hours and have got nowhere. I found this [link](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2373929?q=custom%20forma) explaining to use the code

```
AFNumber_Keystroke(0,0,0,0,"\'",false);
```

So I took this example and applied my format:

```
AFNumber_Keystroke(0,0,0,0,"\SqFt",false);
```

I am using Acrobat Pro X Mac version. The properties tab I put this code under the format, selected the format category to custom and inputted the code under both [Separate times] Custom Format Script and Custom Keystroke Script. Did not work. Just because I used _Format instead of _Keystroke still nothing.

I have used JavaScript in the actions tab before for another situation and it seemed to work, so I came up with this script:

```
this.getField("Area") = event;
event = this.value+ 'SqFt';
```

*Onblur, ran as JavaScript

Anyone have an idea? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need the sqFT for further use (such as calculations)?

If not, you would use the Format event, and add the following line of code:

```
event.value += event.value + " SqFt" ;
```

And that should do it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Max! I forgot the operator +=. The solution you provided worked, but added the event twice, so the correct solution is:

```
event.value += " SqFt" ;
```

Also under the Arbitrary Mask option in special category:

```
99.99SqFt (for 2 decimals)
```